# How to open a new console from python script and be able to manage it

Tags: python, cmd

I am writing a script that needs to be able to open a separate console window and read and write to it(on Windows). I want to use telnet and ssh from new consoles and the main console use as a manager

Right now i was trying thoes things:

**main file**

```
import subprocess as sp
from getpass import getpass
import telnetlib
import multiprocessing as mp
import os

def run(command):
    cmd = sp.Popen(command.split(), sp.PIPE)
    com, err = cmd.communicate()
    print(com,err)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    login = input("Podaj login: ")
    password = getpass()

    ip = "10.74.119.252"
    command = f"python LogInConsol.py {ip} {login} {password}"

    process = mp.Process(target=run, args= (command,))
    process.start()
```

**LogInConsol file**

```
import telnetlib
import subprocess as sb
import sys

argv = sys.argv
ip = argv[1]
login = argv[2]
pw = argv[3]

# tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host=ip, port= 23)
# tn.read_until(b"login: ")
command = f"cmd.exe start /k telnet {ip}"
cmd = sb.run(command.split(),sb.PIPE)
com, err = cmd.communicate()
```

But the behavior is such that everything happens in main consol window(from which i start program)

***UPDATE***

This started to work as i wanted it to.

**Main.py**

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE
from getpass import getpass
import telnetlib
import multiprocessing as mp
import threading as th

def run(command):
    cmd = Popen(command, PIPE, creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
    com, err = cmd.communicate()
    print(com,err)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    mp.freeze_support()
    login = input("Podaj login: ")
    password = getpass()
    ip = "10.10.10.10"
    command = f"python LogInConsol.py {ip} {login} {password}"
    process = mp.Process(target=run, args= (command,))
    process.start()
    input("Wait ")
```

**LogInConsol.py**

```
import telnetlib
import subprocess as sp
import sys


argv = sys.argv
ip = argv[1]
login = argv[2]
pw = argv[3]


print(argv)
tn = telnetlib.Telnet(host=ip,port=23)
red = tn.read_until(b"username: ")
print(red)
```

Answer (score 1):

Could try wshshell:

```
1. pip install pywin32-221-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
2. python.exe pywin32_postinstall.py -install  (DOS command line)
```

in script:

```
   import win32com.client
   WshShell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
   WshShell.run("cmd")
```

Comment: I am testing it and i may work. Can you tell me how to get to input and output of new console ?

Comment: take a look at the answer to this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6732543/running-python-script-using-wshshell-run-in-vbs-does-not-generate-output-file

im not too familiar with the library myself so the shell.echo seems to be the answer

Comment: It's hard for me to wrap my mind around this api, the example is not very accurate. Still problem is not solved.

Comment: try using subprocess.communicate. more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25815078/how-to-interact-with-a-terminal-in-python

also subprocess.check_output will give the output of the subprocess call. You must call it correctly, in your example script you are not. try this documentation : https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 1):

Could this be a case of the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)? You need to connect via telnet or ssh, but do you really need that console in between?

You can make telnet connections in python using [telnetlib](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/telnetlib.html?highlight=telnetlib#module-telnetlib) and ssh ones with [paramiko](http://www.paramiko.org/).

Comment: What i want is to start connection from main console but manage the rest from the new one